# Find $ S1$ in the parallelogram below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:

> In the picture; if $ABCD$ is a parallelogram;
> $S3 = 10\,\text{m}^2$ and $S2 = 3\,\text{m}^2$. Calculate $S1$ (Answer: $7\,\text{m}^2$)
> My picture was wrong...I put the right one now...I'm sorry for the mistake
> [image]

My progress:

$S3 = S_{AB} =S_{AGC}=S_{AGB}= 10$

$S1 = \dfrac{S3+S_{GHD}}{2}=\dfrac{BD\cdot h}{2}$

$\dfrac{S_{CGI}}{S_{CIA}}=\dfrac{GI}{AI}$

$\dfrac{3}{S_{OID}}=\dfrac{AI}{ID}$

$S_{OAC} = \dfrac{AC\cdot r}{2}$

....???

Comment: AOI = HDG... could this help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to see that $S_{BOC} + S_{AOD}$ is equal to half the area of the parallelogram.

On the other hand, $S_{ACD}$ is clearly also equal to half the area of the parallelogram.

Taking out their intersection, we get $S_1 + S_2 = S_3$.

The circle is for decoration.

Comment: @WhatsUp Interesting observation - the selection of is dividing always the parallelogram into two couples of triangles equal in area.

Comment: 1) How is BOC + AOD = 1/2 Area of //gym or S1+S2 =1/2 Area of //gm ?

Comment: What is your proof for 1 & 2