# Relation between the area of the four sections inside a parallelogram determined by four vertices and a random point inside it.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

To note: There is a question on site with same diagram but the questions I ask regarding this diagram , are different.

[Find $ S1$ in the parallelogram below](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4348726/878401)

The Question:

> [image]
>
> Given:
>
> $S_1 = 10\ \mathrm{ m^2}$ , $S_2=3\ \mathrm{ m^2}$. Find $S_1$.

$S$ in the diagram is the shaded region. Answer is $7\ \mathrm{ m^2}.$

I read an answer & it wrote the given relations to be true:

1. $S_1+S_2=S_3$
2. $S_{BOC}+ S_{AOD} =\frac12\cdot\text{Area of  parallelogram}$

Q1: I am not able to figure out as to how the 1st relation is true.

For the 2nd point. I have Been trying to figure it out for long , I noticed something.

Point is $O$ is not a center of the parallelogram. From this point , four lines are drawn which touch the vertices of the parallelogram . Therefore, 4 types of different areas can be formed.

The relation states that :

$S_{AOD} + S_{BOC} = S_{AOB} + S_{DOC} =\frac12\cdot\text{Area of parallelogram}$

Q2: If I take any point in a parallelogram like the point $O$, 4 types of areas will be formed. Can we say that out of these 4 areas, sum of 2 = sum of other 2 areas always ? I’m not sure if this is true.

Comment: #2 and #3 are reasons that #1 is true. For #3, clearly AC is diagonal of parallelogram as shown in figure. What is your doubt?

Comment: You could have asked in comments to the original answer and anyone of us could have explained. Why create a new question to an existing answer unless the original answerer has left the site or is not responding...

Comment: @ACB //gm is a way to represent parallelogram.

Comment: @MyMolecules I didn’t understand why is #1 true. For #2,#3 , I wrote a thinking but I am not sure if I’m correct. So , I have tried but want to know where am I going wrong.

Comment: @MathLover 1) I had so much to write. To make the Q looks simpler + also show what I have tried is what I believe is what MSE represents. 2) I could only message the user who had posted. I didn’t know how could I ask as well.

Comment: @MathLover https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4348726/878401 . The Q , similar to mine. I am having difficulty in understanding the answer posed by the user as to why are they true.

Comment: @ACB Done mostly.

Comment: You should probably link the question

Comment: @Buraian That’s what u meant.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get why $\text{Eq.2}$ and $\text{Eq.3}$ are true, after which $\text{Eq.1}$ is a piece of cake.

Consider a vertical line segment $\overline{EF}$ passing through $O$, perpendicular to $\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{BC}$, with $E$ lying on $\overline{BC}$ and $F$ on $\overline{BC}.$

$\begin{align} 
\frac12\cdot [ABCD] &= \frac12\cdot EF\cdot AD\\ 
&= \frac12\cdot (EO + OF) \cdot AD \\
&=\frac12 \cdot EO\cdot AD + \frac12\cdot OF \cdot BC \quad (AD = BC)\\
&= [\triangle AOD] + [\triangle BOC]
\end{align}$

(where $AB$ represents length of line segment $\overline{AB}$ and $[\quad]$ represents area of polygon)

$\text{Eq3}$ is very easy now, with either similar logic or subtraction from total area of the parallelogram.

Finally, for $\text{Eq.1}$, let $S_4$ = area of triangle formed when $S_2$ is removed from $\triangle AOD$:

$\begin{align}
S_1 + S_2 &= S_1 + (S_2 + S_4) - S_4 \\ 
&= [\triangle AOD] + [\triangle BOC]  - S_4 \\ 
&= \frac12\cdot [ABCD] - S_4 \\ 
&= [\triangle ACD] - S_4 \quad (\because\triangle ACD\cong\triangle CAB)\\ 
&= S_3
\end{align}$

Comment: Any general point $O$ will have the same property.

Comment: I have understood the points & u have written them very nicely. About Q2 which I have written , is that a true property? Could u please elaborate upon that point.

Comment: I have written about at the end.

Comment: @S.M.T yes what you ask in $Q2$ is a true property for any interior point. You take a point $P$ inside and then make $4$ triangles by connecting to vertices of the parallelogram, sum of area of two triangles made with $AB$ and $CD$ is equal to the sum of area of triangles made with $BC$ and $DA$.

Comment: @S.M.T when I proved that [AOD] + [BOC] = 1/2 [ABCD], I never specified what point O was! Point O is just ANY random point inside. To convince yourself, take any point O at your will, draw EF on paper, and go through the proof over again.

Comment: Of course O should be inside (or on) ABCD for this to hold. As someone said above, the circle is only for decoration purposes, it has no influence on the proof. Also look at the corner case when O converges to a corner (let O = D). Then out of the 4 triangles, 2 triangles become lines with area 0, and other 2 become the half triangles of the parallelogram.